# testing input type date through laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, testing, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

Trying to test following input element

```
<input name="birthdate" id="#birthdate" class="input" type="date">
```

Through Laravel Dusk
I've tried

```
$browser->type('birthdate', now()->toDateString())
```

end even

```
->type('birthdate', '31-01-2003')

->type('birthdate', '31-Jan-2003')
```

[image]
[image]

No data is inserted and even Submit button is not pressed. Dump reveals that I will remain on the form without submitting.

Chrome version:

```
(Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.98)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 
"laravel/dusk","version": "v4.0.4",
```

Thanks

Comment: What versions of Dusk and Chrome are you using?

Comment: added to my original post. I believe latest stable version both.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/104? Does it work with `type="text"`?

Comment: I did check this solution but unfortunately doesn't work. Also "text" type would pass the test however I need a date from user so typing "John Doe" instead of birth date would't be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to format it properly

```
->type('birthdate', $newuser->birthdate->format('mdY'))
```